# python scipy ode dopri5 'larger nmax needed'

Tags: python, scipy

While using **scipy 0.13.0**, `ode(f).set_integrator('dopri5')`, I get the error message -

`larger nmax is needed`

I looked for `nmax` in the `ode.py` but I can't see the variable. I guess that the number call for integration exceeds the allowed default value.

How can I increase the nmax value?

Comment: Interestingly, there is no `nmax` in the entire `scipy.integrate` module.

Comment: But in the error messages in _ode.py for the dopri5 include this message.

Answer (score 3):

`nmax` refers to the maximum number of internal steps that the solver will take. The default is 500.  You can change it with the `nsteps` argument of the `set_integrator` method.  E.g.

`ode(f).set_integrator('dopri5', nsteps=1000)`

(The Fortran code calls this `NMAX`, and apparently the Fortran name was copied to the error message in the python code for the "dopri5" solver.  In the `ode` class API, all the solvers ("dopri5", "vode", "lsoda", etc) consistently call this solver parameter `nsteps`, so scipy should change the error message used in the python code to say `nsteps`.)

Comment: I tried increasing value of nsteps, but it didn't work. I received the same error message.

Comment: nmax is Maximal number of allowed steps and  default value is 100000.

Comment: The default in the Fortran code is 10000, but the default value of `nsteps` in the Python code is 500.  Take a look at the `__init__` method of the `dopri5` class in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/_ode.py

Comment: Can you add the code that causes the error to the question?  Preferably the code should be pared down to the minimal example that still generates the error.

Comment: sorry, I could not add because i use another computer for the python and it's usb ports are disabled and no internet :(

Comment: I use interpolation subroutine in the python code. When i disabled this interpolation subroutine, i do not get this error. Can interpolation subroutine cause that error? Also when i changed the boundary conditions, no error occurs.

Comment: I wish i could add the code, i get this error for a specified case.